# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have seen many questions like this but couldn't find related answer. Here is my script file

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []).controller("myController",function ($scope) {
      var employee = {
      firstname: "mak",
      lastname: "d",
      gender: "male"
    };
    $scope.employee= employee;
});
```

I not sure why i am getting this error. I see below text on browser

```
{{   `employee.firstname`   }}
{{   `employee.lastname`    }}
{{   `employee.gender`   }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error results from the **`$injector`** being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

**Working demo :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var employee = {
        firstname: "mak",
        lastname: "d",
        gender: "male"
    };

    $scope.employee= employee;
});

<div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
  {{  employee.firstname }} {{  employee.lastname }} {{  employee.gender }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try rename your Script.js in `app.js`:

```
 var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[]);

    myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {

var employee = { firstname: "mak", lastname: "d", gender: "male" };

                        $scope.employee= employee;
        });
```

or :

```
 angular.module("myModule",[]);
    angular.module("myModule").controller("myController", function ($scope) {
 var employee = { firstname: "mak", lastname: "d", gender: "male" };

                            $scope.employee= employee;
            });
```

Comment: still getting the same text on browser. following is my html code   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        {{employee.firstname}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{employee.lastname}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{employee.gender}}
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I can see below error                                                                              Unknown provider: employeeProvider <- employee <- myController, what could be the resolution.

Comment: sorry what should i check

Answer (score 0):

> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly

and also make sure you have include controller js file in index file.